# I am downloading a photo from URL and asking for runtime permission, but it crashes for the first time when permission is granted

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-error, android-download-manager, runtime-permissions

My app crashes when it allows the permission for the first time then it downloads the file accurately.

**Stacktrace:**

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.unsplashapi/com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5360)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2296)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity.startDownloading(ViewPagerActivity.kt:96)
        at com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(ViewPagerActivity.kt:130)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8571)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8419)
```

**My Code**

```kotlin
//...
downloadBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        } else {
            startDownloading(list)
        }
    } else {
        startDownloading(list)
    }
}
//...
        
private fun startDownloading (list:ArrayList<ImageModel>){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val downloadList = list[viewPager.currentItem].urls.full
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadList))
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "/unsplash/${list[viewPager.currentItem].id}.jpg"
            )
            .setTitle("Downloading").setDescription("downloading image").setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    val manager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    myId = manager.enqueue(request)
    var br = object :BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context:Context ?, intent:Intent ?){
            var id = intent ?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
            if (id == myId) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this @ViewPagerActivity,
                "Downloaded Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
    registerReceiver(br, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode:Int, permissions:Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when(requestCode) {
        STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                startDownloading(ArrayList < ImageModel > ())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by examining your stack trace.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.unsplashapi/com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5360)
        ...
```

Specifically the, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. See documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) for more information.

An **example** of such an error is:

```java
int[] array = int[1];
array[1] = 3;
```

In your case, you might have something like this:

```java
T[] t = T[2];
t[11] = //something   <--------- the error, i.e. accessing an index that isn't that is larger than 2.
```

---

Now that we know what an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, lets look at your code, and ALWAYS use the stack trace!

We use the latter portion of the stack trace for anaylsis

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity.startDownloading(ViewPagerActivity.kt:96)
        at com.example.unsplashapi.ViewPagerActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(ViewPagerActivity.kt:130)
```

go to the function `onRequestPermissionsResult`, then lets look at the next line in the stack trace which is `startDownloading` so we know that:

```
onRequestPermissionsResult --- > startDownloading
```

That line is:

```java
startDownloading(ArrayList < ImageModel > ())
```

Inside of `startDownloading`, the 2nd line you have:

```java
val downloadList = list[viewPager.currentItem].urls.full
```

Does this look oddly familiar to the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` I described earlier?

---

**Solution:**

```kotlin
list[viewPager.currentItem].forEach((item) {
    // item.urls.full
})
```

or perform a length check